# installing and running a script file on android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, file, adb

To make use of ASL library for my screen shot app on android,i need to install a script file (run.ps1) and run it on emulator ... So can any one tell me how can i do it...should i do it using ADB or using Eclipse...?

Answer (score 0):

A `.ps1` file appears to be a PowerShell script. PowerShell is a Windows application. Android is not Windows. Hence, if it is indeed a PowerShell script, you cannot run that script on Android.

Comment: actually i wanted to build a screen shot app on android using ASL ...here is the reference http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/Usage

Comment: @manju: The documentation says that the script is a "PowerShell script recommended for Windows systems". That script does not run on the Android device, it runs on your host Windows PC.

Comment: That means whenever i want to take screen shot i should connect my device to a host PC....?